# add class name outside of lifecycle methods in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to add a class to a component in React,

```
  componentDidMount() {
      console.log(document.getElementById('mainNav').scrollTop);

          let element = document.getElementById('mainNav')
          if (element.scrollTop  > 100) {
             element.classList.add("navbar-scrolled")
          }

  }
```

i appreciate that this isn't working because when the component gets mounted, scrollTop = 0 and this isn't checked so isn't getting picked up on scroll...

my question is, where would i put this to ensure it gets picked up when Im scrolling, how to check scrollTop dynamically when it changes?

Comment: add a scroll event listener?

Comment: Or do this in the componentDidUpdate instead of componentDidMount

Answer (score 0):

put it in `scroll` listener:

```js
componentDidMount() {
  let element = document.getElementById('mainNav')
  this.scrollListener = () => {
    if (element.scrollTop > 100) {
      element.classList.add("navbar-scrolled");
    }
  }
  window.addEventListener("scroll", this.scrollListener);
}

componentWillUnmount() {
  window.removeEventListener("scroll", this.scrollListener);
}
```